# Cycles rendering not working in viewport

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

As you probably know, while you're working on a model, you can change the render engine, and that will be what it looks like both in the rendered image and in the viewport.  However, when I'm working on the model, the viewport always uses Eevee, even when I switch to Cycles, but the rendered image (F12) still uses Cycles.  How do I fix this?

EDIT: another thing to mention is that whenever I'm on Cycles, the "Device" select is grayed-out, but I can still click on it.

Comment: Did you switch to rendered view mode in the viewport?

Comment: I can't find where I go to change that.

Comment: Its on the top right corner where there are 4 buttons with sphere things on them. To switch to rendered view mode click the button farthest right.